# Getting Error while trying to use afterscenario in background

Tags: karate

I am posting this question first time, please execuse me for any mistakes.

Getting Error while trying to use afterscenario in background 
unexpected 'configure' key: 'afterScenario'
karate version used is  0.6.2

Comment: Please add some more context to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because `afterScenario` hooks were introduced in version 0.7.0

Please upgrade.

Comment: thanks peter, its working fine after upgrading to 0.7.0 version.